# Best way to work on 15000 work items that need 1-2 I/O calls each

Tags: c#, .net, performance, task-parallel-library

I have a C#/.NET 4.5 application that does work on around 15,000 items that are all **independent of each other**. Each item has a relatively small cpu work to do (no more than a few milliseconds) and 1-2 I/O calls to WCF services implemented in .NET 4.5 with SQL Server 2008 backend. I assume they will queue concurrent requests that they can't process quick enough? These I/O operations can take anywhere from a few milliseconds to a full second. The work item then has a little more cpu work(less than 100 milliseconds) and it is done.

I am running this on a **quad-core machine with hyper-threading**. Using the task parallel library, I am trying to get the best performance with machine as I can with as little waiting on I/O as possible by running those operations asynchronously and the CPU work done in parallel.

Synchronously, with no parallel processes and no async operations, the application takes around **9 hours to run**. I believe I can speed this up to under an **hour or less** but I am not sure if I am going about this the right way.

**What is the best way to do the work per item in .NET?** Should I make 15000 threads and have them doing all the work with context switching? Or should I just make 8 threads (how many logical cores I have) and go about it that way? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Adding mandatory [horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) link... Try anything and see if it meets *your goals* - basic `await Task.WhenAll(...)` or `Parallel.For` should not take too long to write/measure...

Comment: Thanks for the comment @AlexeiLevenkov. I am testing this the best I can but have been having issues that accurately represent my data that I can use. I wanted to make sure I was even on the right track in my first approach in the first place before I took a few weeks to implement the solutions this way.

Comment: Try 8 threads and see how it goes.From my experience, too many threads will very likely degrade the performance to a crawl. Real life example: I had a situation almost exactly the same as yours. No threading, the whole thing took about 2 hours for 1100 things to compute. Between 4 and 12 threads got me down to 30 minutes. 1100 threads...the FIRST response came back after 7 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

My usuall suggestion is TPL Dataflow.

You can use an `ActionBlock` with an `async` operation and set the parallelism as high as you need it to be:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<WorkItem>(wi =>
{
    DoWork(wi);
    await Task.WhenAll(DoSomeWorkAsync(wi), DoOtherWorkAsync(wi));
}, 
new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions{ MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1000 });

foreach (var workItem in workItems)
{
    block.Post(workItem);
}

block.Complete();
await block.Completion;
```

That way you can test and tweak `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` until you find the number that fits your specific situation the most.

For CPU intensive work having higher parallelism than your cores doesn't help, but for I/O (and other async operations) it definitely does so if your CPU intensive work is short then I would go with at least a 1000.

Comment: For IO intensive work it depends on how much concurrency the backend service can provide. I doubt many services can withstand 1000 concurrent requests. (+1)

Comment: I am calling 2 WCF services implemented in .NET 4.5 with SQL Server 2008 backend. I assume they will queue the concurrent requests that they can't process quick enough?

Comment: @JasonRoell It really depends on their implementation. I can only suggest setting MaxDegreeOfParallelism through a config file and test different values in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't want to kick off 15000 threads and let them all thrash it out.  If you can make your I/O methods completely async - meaning I/O completion ports based - then you can get some very nice controlled parallelism going on.
If you have to tie up threads whilst waiting for I/O you're going to be massively limiting your ability to process the items.

```
TaskFactory taskFactory = new TaskFactory(new WorkStealingTaskScheduler(Environment.ProcessorCount));

public Job[] GetJobs() { get { return new Job[15000];} }

public async Task ProcessJobs(Job[] jobs)
{
    var jobTasks = jobs.Select(j => StartJob(j));

    await Task.WhenAll(jobTasks);
}

private async Task StartJob(Job j)
{
    var initialCpuResults = await taskFactory.StartNew(() => j.DoInitialCpuWork());

    var wcfResult = await DoIOCalls(initialCpuResults);

    await taskFactory.StartNew(() => j.DoLastCpuWork(wcfResult));
}

private async Task<bool> DoIOCalls(Result r)
{
    // Sequential...
    await myWcfClientProxy.DoIOAsync(...); // These MUST be fully IO completion port based methods [not Task.Run etc] to achieve good throughput
    await mySQLServerClient.DoIOAsync(...); 
    // or in Parallel...
    // await Task.WhenAll(myWcfClientProxy.DoIOAsync(...), mySQLServerClient.DoIOAsync(...));

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hm, this task scheduler will not limit the number of outstanding async IOs. As soon as an async IO starts the task gets off the CPU and the scheduler is out of the game.

Comment: Yeh that was kind of the point. Scheduler deals with the CPU bound operations and the IOs are left to their own devices. Ofcourse with quite so many you may get other bottlenecks (running out of ports etc etc) but it solves what I consider the main issues which are reducing context switching by controlling CPU concurrency and enabling IO to happen without using as many resources.